# G Suite (Google Apps) without a custom domain?

Tags: google-workspace, domain, google-workspace-for-business

Do I need to use a custom domain with Google's [G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com) (formerly Google Apps)? I can't see any way to sign up for the service without wiring up a domain. Isn't there some kind of default domain that could be used, like `first.last@gsuite.com`?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom domain"?  G-Suite works with any domain you wish.  The e-mail accounts all use that domain to work.  Once you select a domain name to use, there is no changing it later.

Comment: Right. I don't want my own domain. I just want to use the service without wiring up a domain.

Comment: Thats what Gmail is for.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Not exactly. G Suite has certain features and integrations that are not available to a standard Gmail account.

Comment: @Sam can you give examples. I think extra features you can purchase in gmail also.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Like sharing a document with all other users in your organization (without making it public).

Comment: another example:  I want to use google-outlook plugin. It works only with paid G Suite service. Can't sync outlook without this ransomware, and google don't release this app in any other plan  @ShashwatKumar

Answer (score 4):

This is according to [GSuite](https://support.google.com/a/topic/3540977):

> To use Google services **with your organization or team**, you **need a domain name**. This name will be in your users' email address as in maria@yourdomain.com. And it can be in your company web site address, as in www.yourdomain.com.

Comment: Can you offer a link where you found that quote?

Answer (score 0):

There's no google-provided solution, apparently.
I just verified that with a google customer rep. over an official support chat.

(although, to be fair, and blunt, I had learned that not all google support reps know all the available solutions, so it's worth following up)